# Is it possible to increment a slice of a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, slice

I have a list say, `l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`. Now, I want to increment all the elements within the given indices `l` and `r`.

If `l==2` and `r==5` the list should be `[1,2,4,5,6,7,7]`.

I can do this with a "for loop" running from `l` to `r`. But is there any way to do it in less time?

Comment: stride is probably what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a slice assignment and a list comprehension:

```
>>> li= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> li[l:r+1]= [v+1 for v in li[l:r+1]]
>>> li
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7]
```

Comment: @anil Even though I like this solution a lot (it's really concise and short), keep in mind that it won't be necessary faster than looping through the array and setting the elements, because you need to create another list and assign those elements. Also, this approach could be way harder to read to beginners or just people reading your code.